# Certain data extraction from matrix (R)

Tags: r, matrix, row, extract, col

I have a matrix with column 1 containing several identical numerical values. The corresponding row values, however, are all different.

I have illustrated the situation in the picture below.

[image]

The red circles highlight one of the groups that have same column-value. I need the average of the 'MSE' for the groups defined by having same values of 'lambda'. 
In the above example, one of the averages I am looking for would be (0.9769541 + 0.9902620 + 1.0008839 + 1.0108471 + 0.9981030 + 0.9858211) / 6.

Comment: Anything you already tried? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Well, I did try the following (call the matrix A)

A <- as.data.frame(A)

A[A$lambda == 'value of lambda',]

but it returns <0 rows>

Comment: One option: Try `?rowsum` and use `?tapply` or similar for the denominator.